# Как использовать Auth::user() в middleware Laravel при использовании sanctum?

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-8

Всем привет! Подскажите, использую sanctum для авторизации, решил добавить свою middleware, которая должна проверять Auth::user()
Однако при таком вызове:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->middleware('activated')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/name', function (Request $request) {
        return response()->json(['user' => auth()->user()]);
    });
});
```

Auth::user() внутри activated возвращает null;

Однако, если использовать эту middleware к конкретному маршруту, а не к группе - всё работает:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/name', function (Request $request) {
        return response()->json(['user' => auth()->user()]);
    })->middleware('activated');
});
```

Но это неудобно, ведь маршрутов могут быть сотни. Сколько я понимаю, проблема в порядке вызова middleware.

Пробовал в Http/Kernel.php делать так:

```
 protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserActivation::class
];
```

Не даёт положительного эффекта.

Как запустить activated после auth:sanctum, чтобы иметь внутри неё Auth::user()?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'activated'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/name', function (Request $request) {
        return response()->json([
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    });
});
```

И проверьте зарегистрирован ли **middleware** в **app\Http\Kernel.php**